# Parse query not working in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I have a query that is trying to find users in a database in Parse. For some reason, after updating to Swift 2.0 I am getting the following error for the following code.

> Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> Void' to
>   expected argument type 'PFQueryArrayResultBlock?'

This is the code that is giving me the error and I am not sure why. The entire function is posted below.

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

This is the entire function if it helps any.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    let fullnameQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    fullnameQuery.whereKey("fullname", containsString: searchBar.text)

    let usernameQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    usernameQuery.whereKey("username", containsString: searchBar.text)

    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([fullnameQuery, usernameQuery])

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

         if error != nil {

             let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
         }

         if let objects = results as? [PFObject] {

            self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for object in objects {

                self.searchResults.append(object)

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.table.reloadData()
                self.searchController.resignFirstResponder()
           }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call this correctly now you need to use the following

```
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            if error == nil {
                for object in objects {
                    self.searchResults.append(object)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.table.reloadData()
                    self.searchController.resignFirstResponder()
                }     
            } else {
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better, with swift the compiler is great at inferring types based on method signatures. All you really need is this:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (results, error ) -> Void in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    ...
```

Comment: In Swift 2 there's no need for defining that it's a `PFObject` and `NSError`. Check pbush25's answer